# How can I get the DirectWrite PadWrite sample to work?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, directwrite

I'm trying to learn about the DirectWrite API so I can get a flexible solution to the problem of rendering text from any culture, and potentially use it to incorporate rich text editing into an application with a lot more control than the "canned" ways of editing/displaying text.

The [PadWrite sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd941792%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) looks great, and shows off how well-designed the API is - this is Microsoft's own screenshot of how it should look:

[image: Screenshot of PadWrite]

The example text includes a line that starts "Mixed scripts:" In the source code all the sample text is specified by a single C++ `wchar_t[]` literal, and the mixed scripts all display correctly in Visual Studio 2012's code editor. If I copy and paste them into ordinary Windows WordPad they also display correctly. And the Arabic right-to-left section has the correct caret-navigation behaviour in both of those editors.

But none of this works when I actually run the PadWrite sample. Instead I see this:

[image]

It almost looks like it's being converted into UTF-8 and then misinterpreted (which doesn't make sense because it's all being done with `wchar_t`.)

I'm running Windows 8.1. What do I need to do to make PadWrite work as well as WordPad or Visual Studio 2012? Is it a defunct sample from a pre-release version of the API that never got updated?

NB. first warning sign was that PadWrite didn't even compile at first - in the files `EditableLayout.cpp` and `TextEditor.cpp` I had to add this after the `#include` statements:

```
#undef max
#undef min
```

Comment: Oops, I should have saved the file with a BOM >_< I wrote that sample and can confirm that it's not a pre-release version - it was part of the Windows 7 SDK. Glad you got it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an answer on the [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/918b1fa7-57a7-43ae-9149-279e987337af/problem-with-directwrites-padwrite-example?forum=visualstudiogeneral). The problem is that since the sample was created, the Visual C++ compiler has been changed so that it no longer able to detect UTF-8 encoding without the UTF-8 signature being present, whereas Visual Studio still can. And the sample was create so the source files do not have the UTF-8 signature.

As a result, VS's code editor displays the characters correctly in the source file, but when the source is compiled the characters are misinterpreted.

So the solution is to use *Save as*, *Save with Encoding...* and then pick *Unicode (UTF-8 with signature)*.

Comment: I saw the answer on the MSDN forum.  This explains it better.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To build with VS 2013, let Visual Studio convert the project and solution files.  In Common.h delete these lines:

```
#if (_MSC_VER >= 1200) // want to use std::min and std::max
#undef min
#undef max
#define min(x,y) _cpp_min(x,y)
#define max(x,y) _cpp_max(x,y)
#endif
```

The compiler will also complain about unreachable code in a `catch (...)` block in EditableLayout::Clear.  Simply comment out the one-line body of the catch block.  I think there's some mixup between C++-style exceptions and SEH exceptions.